# Identify a scroll bar: Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, scrollbar

I'm writing an extension to Firefox and I'm using JavaScript.
Everytime my mouse uses the scroll bar, my extension goes a little bit crazy.

I'd like to know if there's any way to identify the mouse is on a scroll bar? Some kind of tag/method/special DOM property - anything!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just check whether the mouse is hovering outside the borders of your page/container? Something like `window.screen.width` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bars are usually anonymous elements, they are added to HTML elements automatically but they aren't visible in the DOM. However, `event.originalTarget` will give you these scrollbar elements if they are the event target (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.originalTarget).